# Estimating $E[\operatorname{Tr}(ABABBA..)]$ for random shuffling of $A,B$?

Tags: pr.probability, linear-algebra, random-matrices

How can I estimate the following value where $A,B$ are $d\times d$ matrices and expectation is taken over all random permutations of the product?

$$E_\text{shuffle}[\operatorname{Tr}\underbrace{AA\cdots A}_s \underbrace{BB\cdots B}_s]$$

In my application $A$ is a positive definite diagonal matrix, $B$ is positive definite symmetric rank-1, $\|A+B\|<1$. I need to estimate this in $O(d)$ time for large $d$ and $s\approx d$, any tips?

Empirically, this distribution appears to concentrate around the mean:

[image]

The following appears to hold empirically, is it true?

$$\operatorname{Tr}(ABABAB\ldots AB) \le E_\text{shuffle}[\operatorname{Tr}\underbrace{AA\cdots A}_s \underbrace{BB\cdots B}_s] \le \operatorname{Tr}AA\cdots AA BB\cdots BB$$

Any pointers to the relevant theory appreciated!

Motivation: to estimate $\operatorname{Tr}[(A+B)^{2s}]$ which gives error after $2s$ steps of SGD to solve linear problem with eigenvalues $h$ by following Eq.5 of [Bordelon](https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.02713). $A,B$ is obtained from $h$ like [this](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/42528/approximating-eigenvalues-of-dpr1-matrix-with-special-properties).

[Notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/mathoverflow-simplified-sgd.nb)

Comment: If $B$ is rank $1$, then $B^2 = k B$ for some scalar k, which will simplify a lot of those products.

Comment: Thanks, indeed, it seems a lot of values repeat. The number of unique values of $\operatorname{Tr}(ABA..)$ seems to be predicted by the [integer partition function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Partition_function).

Comment: It's interesting that the partition function is relevant. I would have guessed that for random real matrices it would instead be the number of $2$-coloured necklaces of length $n$, since trace is invariant under cyclic permutation. OEIS: https://oeis.org/A000031

Comment: @MarkWildon I indeed see A000031 if I use generic matrices A,B. If I restrict A to be diagonal and B to be symmetric rank 1, I get https://oeis.org/A052810

Comment: somewhat related, generating function for $\operatorname{Tr}[(A+B)^k]$ has a [simple closed form](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4654692/998) when A+B is diagonal + rank-1

Comment: Are the inequalities above right? It seems like maybe they should be reversed...

Comment: @JasonGaitonde good catch....how did you know?

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov the outer-most inequality is known -- I saw it as Lemma 1.2.: https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~jrl/teaching/cse599Isp21/notes/lecture3.pdf. Not sure about the general case.

Comment: Since $B$ is rank $1$ symmetric positive semidefinite, it can be written as $v v^T$ for some vector $v$. So $Tr(\prod A^{k_i} B) = \prod (v^T A^{k_i} v)$. The latter product is a product of scalars, so the order of the $k_i$ doesn't matter, and we get the partition function.